# Serializing a Java object to CSV

Tags: java, csv

I have a `List<Cat>` (as per the following class):

```
public class Cat {
  public LocalDateTime dob;
  public String name;
  public boolean isHappy;
}
```

and I want to convert it into a multi-line CSV file (i.e. one line per Cat object) which I will then use to load into a DB. The CSV might look like this:

```
"jack",true,"04-20-2000"
"fred",false,"01-01-1997"
```

what is the best way for me to convert from the `List<`Cat>`objects to CSV format? Should I just write my own`CatSerializer` class which does this for me? Or am I better off using some sort of library (I don't know of any libraries).

I'd just like to know what is best practice here.

Comment: I would go ahead and write your own serialization logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use word serialization
Using java8 just loop through items streaming list of Cats then transforming them into list of strings
Having strings dump them to file

Comment: You could provide some code, something like a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1.You can write your CSV Utils to do it.
2.Use Library  [CSV Library](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=33066) like this

```
  public void readeCsv(){   //read CSV
     try { 

     ArrayList<String[]> csvList = new ArrayList<String[]>(); //sava data
     String csvFilePath ="c:/test.csv";
     CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(csvFilePath,',',Charset.forName("SJIS")); 

     reader.readHeaders(); 

     while(reader.readRecord()){ //read by line
    csvList.add(reader.getValues());
    }
    reader.close();

     for(int row=0;row<csvList.size();row++){

     String cell = csvList.get(row)[0]; 
    System.out.println(cell);

    }


     }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex);
    }
    }

    /**
     * write CSV
    */
     public void writeCsv(){
     try {

     String csvFilePath ="c:/test.csv";
     CsvWriter wr =new CsvWriter(csvFilePath,',',Charset.forName("SJIS"));
     String[] contents = {"aaaaa","bbbbb","cccccc","ddddddddd"}; 
    wr.writeRecord(contents);
    wr.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```